# What causes a managed clr not found runtime error in Asp.net 5-Mvc 6 application

Tags: asp.net, clr, asp.net-core

I have written a small asp.net 5 & mvc 6. It compiles without error, but when I attempt to run it, I get a "Cannot load file" error in the browser when IISExpress goes searching in my user\.dnx\ folder for dnx.clr.managed. And the error is correct. There is only a dnx.clr.dll in that runtime folder.

When I perform an Internet search for dnx.clr.managed.dll, I find practically nothing.  Can something tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This was a breaking change from beta6.  I upgraded all by packages to latest and reinstalled the VS tooling and the problem was fixed.

[Here is where the issue is explained](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/51)